# Dependency on either AR 3.2 or AR 4 in gemspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, bundler

I'm working on a gem which works on both Rails 3.2 and Rails 4. The gemspec dependency currently looks like this:

```
spec.add_runtime_dependency 'activerecord', '>= 3.2.0', '< 4.1.0'
```

Is there a way to use the twiddle-wakka for this, most notably because the above would include a Rails 3.3 which I would have to test first. What I mean is sort of the union of the following two dependencies, however, only requiring either of the two:

```
spec.add_runtime_dependency 'activerecord', '~> 3.2'
spec.add_runtime_dependency 'activerecord', '~> 4.0'
```